# How to execute SQL Server Stored Procedure for INSERT from Hibernate?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, hibernate, stored-procedures, jdbc

I have been able to execute a Stored Procedure in hibernate to map the result query into a Java Bean.

For example, I have this file called Profesor.hbm.xml:

```
<hibernate-mapping>
        <class name="model.Profesor" table="Profesor" catalog="dbo">
            <id name="idProfesor" type="int">
                <column name="idProfesor" />
                <generator class="assigned" />
            </id>
        <property name="Nombre" type="string">
            <column name="Nombre"  length="25" not-null="false" />
        </property>
        <property name="ApellidoP" type="string">
            <column name="ApellidoP" length="20" not-null="false" />
        </property>

        <property name="ApellidoM" type="string">
            <column name="ApellidoM" length="20" not-null="false" />
        </property>
            </class>

        <sql-query name="getProfesors" callable="true">
        <return alias="getProfesors" class="model.Profesor">

        <return-property name="idProfesor" column="idProfesor"/>
        <return-property name="Nombre" column="Nombre"/>
        <return-property name="ApellidoP" column="ApellidoP"/>
        <return-property name="ApellidoM" column="ApellidoM"/>
        </return>
        exec getProfesors :idTT
        </sql-query>
</hibernate-mapping>
```

And then in my Profesor class I have the following code:

```
SessionFactory sf = new Configuration().configure().buildSessionFactory();
session = sf.getCurrentSession();

public List <Profesor> getProfesors(String idTT){
    session.beginTransaction();

    query.setString("idTT", idTT);

return query.list();
}
```

This works perfectly, I have no problem, the stored procedure executes and it populates my model Class named Profesor with the results.

Now I have another stored procedure which INSERTs data to create a new Profesor in the Database.

I tried something like this with no success:

```
session.beginTransaction();
Connection c = session.connection();
CallableStatement cs = c.prepareCall( "{call addProfesor(?,?,?)}" ) ;
cs.setString(1, "George");
cs.setString(2, "Williams");
cs.setString(3, "Mathematics");

cs.executeUpdate();
```

It doesn't even show me an error message, the data just won't insert. 
I was also reading that just like there is a <"sql-query"> tag, there is a <"sql-insert">
but then I can't see the way to call that <"sql-insert"> because it doesn't have a "name" attribute just like sql-query does.

With <"sql-query"> we could do:

```
 Query query =session.getNamedQuery("getProfesors");
```

Just like I showed before, but since sql-insert doesnt have that attribute name I don't know how to do it. I'm also forced to use Stored procedures since it's a very special requirement, otherwise I would have used other Hibernate persistance features.

Any help would be really appreciated.

Comment: It is very complicated to configure the ORM to use stored procedures for everything. I just mean that you should not do this by choice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Another way to do it is call the stored proc from a prepared statement. This is potentially useful if the stored procedure updates more than one record (batch updates).

```
PreparedStatement ps = getSession().connection().prepareStatement("{exec sp_batchRateUpdate}");
ps.execute();
```

Please note though: hibernate sessions' connection() method has been deprecated since Hibernate 3.2.4 (https://hibernate.onjira.com/browse/HHH-2603)
An alternative to this deprecation temporarily, we can use:

```
PreparedStatement ps = ((SessionFactoryImplementor)sessionFactory).getConnectionProvider()
                    .getConnection().prepareStatement("{exec sp_batchRateUpdate}");
ps.execute();
```

Answer (score 1):

You can specify "custom sql" for insert, update and delete. See [the documentation](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.3/reference/en/html/querysql.html#querysql-cud) about it.

These are not named queries. They are always used when Hibernate inserts, updates or deletes this entity.

Comment: I checked that documentation and I tried modifying my Profesor.hbm.xml adding this line of code:

    <sql-insert callable="true">{call addProfesor (?, ?, ?, ?, ?)}</sql-insert>

inside the <class> tag but then I don't know how to call it from my Java code, please help

Comment: I can't find any example of this, could you lead me somewhere?

Comment: You don't call it directly from java. It is always called when the entity is inserted.